# UITextField doesn't seem to be calling textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to disable UITextField from opening the keyboard but I am having trouble

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface XXViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextField* someTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* someTextField;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation XXViewController

@synthesize someTextField;


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    return NO;  
}
...
```

I am sure this is a very simple problem. I have been searching for ages and couldn't find a solution

Thanks Advance

EDIT:
NSLog isn't being called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do:

```
[someTextField setDelegate:self];
```

Because although your class can be a delegate you never set it as the delegate for the UITextField you are using.

Comment: Oh, Do I feel like an idiot. I done this in viewDidLoad I am assuming that is wrong even though it works now. Thanks EDIT: Just read what you added makes alot more sense now. I feel even more stupid. You're the man.

Comment: you have to call this function in viewDidLoad. dont call it in init functions.